# C# Print View to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried Rotativa and PdfGenerator, but it seems like they emulate a browser, or something like that.

The issue is that my view can only be saw by authenticated users.

How can I prevent not authenticated users from accessing this PDF?

An example of code I am using currently is:

```
    [AllowOperationsOnly]
    public ActionResult PDFReport(DateTime date)
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Report", date);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowOperationsOnly]
    public ActionResult Report(DateTime date)
    {
        // my code...
        return View();
    }
```

The resulting PDF is the page where users are redirected for when they are not authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the actions that you want to only allow authenticated users to access with an [`[Authorize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute:

```
[AllowOperationsOnly]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult PDFReport(DateTime date)
{
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Report", date);
}

[HttpGet]
[AllowOperationsOnly]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Report(DateTime date)
{
    // my code...
    return View();
}
```

The `[Authorize]` attribute supports all sorts of additional overloads that allow you to define specifics such as roles or users that you want to allow access to a decorated action / controller if needed.

**Regarding Rotativa**

Based on [this seemingly related GitHub issue](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/120), it looks like you may have to explicitly pass through any authentication tokens or cookie information to Rotativa in order for it to work as expected:

```
return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Report")
{
        FormsAuthenticationCookieName = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        Cookies = cookies
};
```

Several other resolutions also recommend trying the `ViewAsPdf()` method instead, which may also avoid the authentication issue (assuming you use the `[Authorize]` attribute to handle that within your application and then simply serve the PDF:

```
[AllowOperationsOnly]
public ActionResult PDFReport(DateTime date)
{
    return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Report", date);
}
```

Comment: Rion, I removed all others attributes besides `[Authorize]` and it didn't work.

Comment: You were still able to access one of the Controller Actions decorated with `[Authorize]` while not authenticated? What does your `[AllowOperationsOnly]` attribute look like? It seems like there is probably some logic in there that may be interacting with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: No, I just removed `[AllowOperationsOnly]` and left `[Authorize]` only, and it didn't work. Asnwering the question, we have a "problem" with IT team, they manage the AD server, we just authenticate through there, permissions are granted in our application, "operations" is a permission group.
My guess is that both Rotativa and PdfGenerator emulate a browser accessing the URL in a brand new session, without the authentication cookies.

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/120) looks like it might be related. Apparently you can configure the appropriate cookies to pass through to Rotativa using something similar to that, might be worth exploring.

Comment: Adding [Authorize] attribute & using Rotativa.ViewAsPdf() fixed my issue.